# Override JSON data in Django RestFramwork

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

Right now with the current Views functions I am getting the data given below:

```
{"item": "zxmnb",
"category": "zxc",
"price": "zxc",
"restaurant": 1}
```

Here is my views file:

```
class RestaurantMenuView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'item'
    serializer_class = MenuSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Menu.objects.all()
```

But the issue is I want the data to be in a format as:

```
{"restaurant": "name"
"item":"some item",
"category": "some category",
"price": "some price"
}
```

I want to mention that Restaurant is another model in my models class,Now I know that if I use restaurant I will only get the pk. But what I want is the JSON to be displayed like that.

Comment: your expected output isn't a JSON

Comment: Hey I updated the output. Can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you add your model and serializer?

Comment: This answer really helped [If you are stuck in same situation check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306071/return-dictionary-instead-of-array-in-rest-framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you redefine the to_representation() function. Something like this:

```
class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        restaurants = RestaurantSerializer(instance=obj, 
        context=self.context).data
        data = []
        for restaurant in restaurants:
            data.append(
                {
                    "restaurant": {
                        "item": obj.item,
                        "category": obj.category,
                        "price": obj.price,
                        "name": restaurant.name,
                    }
                }
            )
        return data
```

Without looking at your models or why you want restaurant in there, I added the for loop in order to show you that you can pretty much access any of the data in your to_representation() and put it in any sort of format you want. I use this when I'm trying to render my JSON objects into XML in a specific way. Hope this helps.

Also check out the documentation: 
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior

Another solution that you could consider is adding a Foreign Key on your Menu model back to the Restaurant, then you could define your serializer like this:

```
class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    menu = MenuViewSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = [
            "id",
            "name",
            "menu",
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "menu": {"read_only": True},
        }
```

Comment: + I need the whole menu list to be there but it is just showing up the first menu object. here is the field that I am using in my model, menu = mode.ForeignKey(Menu,on_delete=model.CASCADE())

Comment: Have you defined a MenuViewSerializer that explicitly defines all the fields?

Comment: Oh looking at your original questions code: try changing your viewset to this: class RestaurantMenuView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'item'
    serializer_class = RestaurantSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Restaurant.objects.all()

It should return all the menu children that are associated with that restaurant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your `MenuSerializer`. Specifically, you need to change the `restaurant` field to be a `CharField` and also provide a [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) attribute. Something like the following:

```
class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    restaurant = serializers.CharField(source='restaurant.name')
    # ... other stuff in the serializer
```

Here, I am assuming that your `Restaurant` model has a `name` field.

You can read more about Serializer fields here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/

Comment: Hey I need output like { "restaurant": [ { "key": "value"} ] }. what view should I use there to generate this kind of json response?

Comment: What is `[{"key": "value"}]`? Where will those values come from? Maybe you can try https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield